# key board hinding screen in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is code[enter image description here[][1]][1]

hey I am developing a new app that has a comment section show I put Text field in bottom because of better view but I am having a  problem whenever I open my keyboard my half screen gets hide, this is very
bad for user Interface so here I need your help, And when I make resizeToAvoidBottomInset false text field get hide behind keyboard

````
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0.0,
        title: Text(
          "Comments",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Obx(
            () => ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.comments.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Comment(
                      comment: controller.comments[index]['comment'],
                      userid: controller.comments[index]['userid']);
                }),
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          child: CupertinoTextField(
            
            controller: controller.postComment,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            prefix: IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              icon: Icon(Icons.emoji_emotions),
            ),
            //  decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
            suffix: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
              onPressed: () {
                controller.addComment(
                    args, FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
              },
            ),
            placeholder: "Enter a Comment",
          ),
        )
      ]),
    );    ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FER2u.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use [SingleChildScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) if you want to make your content inside column scrollable when keyboard is shown. Here is the example of usage:

```
SingleChildScrollView( 
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.red[600],
        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.red[500],
        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
      ),
      Container(
        height: 250,
        color: Colors.yellow[100],
        child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: but I have a expanded list view that will give error if wrap in singlechildscrollview

Comment: it work without expanded I have to use media query but want to know can i use without media query